# MySQL error - "You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

The error message I got:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''word','group','selfnote') VALUES ('item','a','note to self')' at line 1

The PHP code is:

```
$toq="INSERT INTO articles ('word','group','selfnote') 
VALUES ('$ttle','$wrdr','$snote')";
```

I was trying to find solutins, but they didn't seem to work as echoing gives:

```
INSERT INTO articles ('word','group','selfnote') 
VALUES ('item','a','note to self')
```

which seems nice to me. What is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried running the exact same query in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Obligatory note: `mysql_real_escape_string()` your data, else Bad Things **will** happen, e.g. when `$snote == "It's simple"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use backticks `` ` `` instead of quotes `'` to escape names. Quotes are string delimiters.

```
$toq="INSERT INTO articles (`word`,`group`, `selfnote`) VALUES ('$ttle','$wrdr','$snote')";
```

Answer (score 8):

You've put quotes on your field names. That forces MySQL to treat them as strings, not field names - and you can't insert into strings.

```
INSERT INTO articles (word, group, selfnote) VALUES (....);
```

is the correct syntax. The only quoting type allowed on field names is the use of backticks to escape reserved word fields, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO articles (table, int, varchar)  ...
```

would fail due to the use of 3 reserved words, but adding backticks

```
INSERT INTO articles (`table`, `int`, `varchar`)  ...
```

makes them acceptable as fieldnames.

Comment: Presumably he was trying to avoid the bare keyword `group`. (I don't know whether it's acceptable in this particular context or not.)

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't quote column names with normal quotes (`''`), rather, use backticks (``` `` ```).

Comment: @slapthelownote: The MySQL manual seems to think so; I can't think of any more authoritative resource: "The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`”)". http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 2):

You must remove or replace the quotes of the column names by backticks (`). Since "group" is a keyword, you have to use backticks:

```
INSERT INTO articles (`word`, `group`, `selfnote`) VALUES (....);
```